# How overpowered would a custom Rune/Glyph of Silence be as a trap?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, traps

I was thinking of using a trap against magic users. The idea that I came up with was basically as follows:

> The victim walks into the trap area (a hallway with a width of *Silence*'s area of effect (about 28 feet across max))
>
> Two quite sturdy walls fall from the ceiling (~28 feet apart max)
>
> When the victim goes to cast a spell, they discover that they can not speak and thus cannot fulfill the verbal requirements that almost every spell has due to the fact that a rune/glyph (not sure which is the correct one) casts Silence and continues to maintain the *Silence* spell.

My main question is: **How overpowered would this trap be against magic users?**

The subordinate question:
Would it be fair to pit players against this (the setting would be in BBEG's lair) trap?
How would I implement a trap like this?

Comment: Yes, it is about a homebrew.

Comment: If you have a homebrew trap, you need to give us the full mechanics for it so we can judge it. If you want to know how to build a trap like that, you should probably ask that specifically.

Comment: By "Zone of Silence" are you actually referring to the _silence_ spell? Or a custom spell/effect?

Comment: I don't think [gm-techniques] is an appropriate tag here. It is typically used for out-of-game concepts or story-telling aspects, not the development of homebrew. That's what the homebrew tag is for.

Comment: I feel that for "overpowered" you need to give some idea of the level of the party.  For a group at 1st level the answer is different than for a group at 8th level.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast it's a hypothetical party.

Comment: @PeregrineLennert FYI, standard way to draw more attention to getting your question reopened is [to ask a question on meta about it](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=Can%20my%20glyph%20of%20silence%20question%20be%20reopened?&tags=support+specific-question+closed-questions). That links to a partly filled-out template for you; link back to this question in the body. I'll leave your flag pending for now, for other moderators more familiar with D&D 5e to check in on, but bringing up this question on meta will get other D&D 5e experts' eyes on it too.

Comment: @doppelgreener Thanks! I wasn't sure, as I had heard  the term "flag for reopening" and got confused.

Comment: @PeregrineLennert No worries. "Flag for reopening" sounds like a misnomer, but people can cast reopen votes which pushes the question into a reopen review queue. Maybe that process was being described. The reviewers may not have agreed this was ready for reopening, but meta will get that fresh set of eyes present, or give you more feedback on what's to be done if it's not ready for reopening.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Not Overpowered (Inherently)

This is something a player can do fully within the rules, which means as a DM it's easy to do and justify should you feel the need to - Your Big Bad or his trap setting assistant needs to know [Glyph of Warding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding) and [Silence](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/silence) creating your so called "Zone of Silence."

Creating a Glyph of Warding containing a Silence spell takes one hour and one 3rd level spell slot, per trigger of the trap. Silence covers a 20ft radius centered on the glyph, so the space the walls contain would have to be fully within that sphere, or the corners would be outside the spell (maybe this is a weakness of the trap for a clever spellcaster).

As to your question of balance, that is fully dependent on what is done with the trapped people. The trapped space could be filled with fire or poison gas, in which case the trap may be too deadly. This trap is merely containment, which is, depending on how paranoid your party is, likely to capture at least one party member. It is likely that if the entire party is held within the trap, they will be stuck there for the duration of the silence (10 minutes). Maybe this time is used to set up an ambush on the party, making the next fight more difficult.

Comment: I see, I was thinking of doing it where it would be permanent and try to separate the spellcaster from the rest of the party, needing to be rescued, but I see that it could be used for an early warning trap if I wanted to get the whole party.

Comment: I think it would be reasonable to make it a permanent silence, but have a backup plan if the whole party gets stuck in there - if they cant cast spells or break the walls it would be easy to starve them to death. I would come up with a reason why the trap would have to be opened eventually

Comment: I had an idea for if the whole party ever gets trapped somewhere, which is to have them draw up new characters, maybe move back quite a ways in time if they're high level, then set a time limit for them to try and rescue their old characters (maybe not telling them of this fact and trying to guide them there)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I am aware of that, I was saying that in the case of a homebrew solution that would make it permanent, I still don't believe the trap to be overpowered

Comment: @SirCinnamon got it.

Comment: +1 here. Yes...this sucks for the magic user. But if the Barbarian gets trapped in here, they're just going to start demolishing walls until they get out.

Comment: @SirCinnamon In chat, Peregrine is interested in the silence spell being permanent once triggered, which isn't all that big of a deal for a DM to choose to do.  But it makes "wait until silence wear off" not part of the solution set. The "home brew" is silence having infinite duration once triggered. We have recommended using silence as is ...

Comment: @KorvinStarmast, I was saying that the permanency was what I was originally thinking of, but I realized that I can just change it depending on how the party is when they are close to hitting the trap

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Right - I think that if the silence is going to be long/infinite, there should be a clear solution to the problem. If it is only ten minutes it should be combined with some kind of other problem which encourages them to find another solution (room filling with water, ambush being set up outside the walls, hostile bug swarms pouring in to the room). If the trap is a triggered silence where the punishment is that you have to wait ten minutes it's hardly a threat.

Answer (score 15):

## A RAW option

It is possible to set up a trap like this using existing rules. You can create a [Glyph of Warding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/spells#GlyphofWarding)(PHB 245-6) as a **Spell Glyph** that is storing [Silence](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/spells#Silence) (PHB 275-6).

This seems to fulfill the effect you're looking for without needing to homebrew. If you have additional mechanical requirements that this doesn't fulfill, please add them to your question.